# how to convert LocalDate to a specific date time format

Tags: java, date-formatting, java-time, localdate, isodate

how to convert ISO_LOCAL_DATE to date time format : yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ in java

Ex: given date: 2016-01-25 to 2016-01-25T00:00:00.000+0100

Comment: 2016-01-25 is likely to be a String. Check the date object it came from

Comment: Easy, just use string concatenation: `s = "2016-01-25"; s += "T00:00:00.000+0100";`

Comment: Do you always want the time of day to be 00:00:00.000? What do you want the UTC offset to be (+0100 in your example)? And is `2016-01-25` a string? A `LocalDate`? Something else?

Comment: Probably not, @blackgreen. Java and JavaScript are vastly different languages. But you are right that there are a lot of related helpful questions out there, the OP would benefit greatly from using his search engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that have got a string, for example `2016-01-25`, and that you want a string containing the start of the day in the JVM’s default time zone (it wasn’t clear from the question). I first define a formatter for the format that you want (it’s ISO 8601):

```
private static DateTimeFormatter formatter
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSxx");
```

Now your conversion goes:

```
    String isoLocalDateString = "2016-01-25";
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(isoLocalDateString);
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = date.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    String dateTimeString = dateTime.format(formatter);
    System.out.println(dateTimeString);
```

When running in my time zone, Europe/Copenhagen, output from this example code is what you asked for:

> 2016-01-25T00:00:00.000+0100

In rare cases where summer time (DST) begins at the first moment of the day, the time of day will not be 00:00:00.000.

For parsing with `ISO_LOCAL_DATE` we don’t need to specify the formatter since this formatter is the default for `LocalDate.parse()`.

All of this said, you should not normally want to convert a date from one string format to another string format. Inside your program keep dates as `LocalDate` objects. When you get string input, parse into a `LocalDate`. Only when you need to give string output, for example in data exchange with another system, format into a string in the required format.

**Link:** [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: thanks, this is what I am looking for

Answer (score 1):

There are various methods on LocalDate for this, including:

- LocalDate::toDateTimeAtCurrentTime()
- LocalDate::toDateTimeAtStartOfDay()
- LocalDate::toDateTime( LocalTime )
- LocalDate::toDateTime( LocalTime , DateTimeZone )

Comment: I think that the OP intended to ask about java.time, the modern Java date and time API, and I think your answer is about Joda-Time. Still +1 for showing that there are different ways that give different results.

Answer (score 0):

It is as simple as `LocalDateTime localDateTime = yourLocalDate.atStartOfDay()`

*Update*
Adding timestamp is as simple as:

```java
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
ZonedDateTime = zdt = localDateTime.atZone(zoneId);
```

Can be put together as

```java
ZonedDateTime zdt = yourLocalDate.atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
```

Comment: `2016-01-25T00:00:00.000+0100` is an `OffsetDateTime`, not a `ZonedDateTime`